# if else, button not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Trying to make the button text change. If button has LBS, then clicking the button should change it to KGS. If button has KGS, then clicking the button should change it to LBS.

The button does nothing, yet the code seems correct to me.

```
from Tkinter import *

myGui=Tk()
myGui.geometry("200x100")
myGui.title("basicGUI")
myGui.configure(bg="gray")

def toggle():
    text = "LBS"
    if text == LBS:
        tglBtn.config(text = KGS)
    else:
        tglBtn.config(text = LBS)

LBS = StringVar
tglBtn = Button(text="LBS",
                textvariable=LBS,
                command=toggle)
tglBtn.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: You set `text` to `"LBS"` every time you run the function, so it'll always do the same thing. You probably want to read what text the button has on it, or even better, store it in a variable as True/False, then set the text depending on the value.

Comment: no clue what you are saying to me. I'm very new to python, I need a better clue please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating a `StringVar` object unless you add parentheses: `LBS = StringVar()`. The name is also misleading, because the `StringVar` will be "LBS" or "KGS". The whole point of a `StringVar` is that the button's text will be updated automatically whenever the `StringVar` changes its value.

```
from Tkinter import *

myGui=Tk()
myGui.geometry("200x100")
myGui.title("basicGUI")
myGui.configure(bg="gray")

def toggle():
    if buttonText.get() == "LBS":
        buttonText.set("KGS")
    else:
        buttonText.set("LBS")

buttonText = StringVar()
buttonText.set("LBS")      # you can't do StringVar("LBS")
tglBtn = Button(textvariable=buttonText,
                command=toggle)
tglBtn.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks so much, it's nice to see others solution. Thanks Again

Comment: after working with your code, I feel it's the best answer, it helped me understand how to use StringVar, .set along with the .get ... I'm sorry I didn't mark yours as best, but I've changed it today. I do like the other answer also. Thanks Jasper

Comment: It is indeed the better answer since it uses more of the tkinter functionality, the other solution is more simple, but hopefully easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In your line `text == LBS`, your are comparing a `string` (`text`) and variable instance (`LBS`, which is a `StringVar`). Either you would to compare `text` and `LBS.get()` or just directly compare the strings directly as in the example below.

---

```
from Tkinter import *

myGui=Tk()
myGui.geometry("200x100")
myGui.title("basicGUI")
myGui.configure(bg="gray")

def toggle():
    text = tglBtn.cget("text")
    if text == "LBS":
        tglBtn.config(text = "KGS")
    else:
        tglBtn.config(text = "LBS")

tglBtn = Button(text="LBS", command=toggle)
tglBtn.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: BIG WOW!!! Yes I knew I wasn't handling text correctly but had no clue how to make the function read it. Your an excellent py programmer, such a clean solution. Thanks

Comment: with `.get()`, you'd get all configuration options at once.